# Cannot make generic type optional for a type alias of an object with two compatible functions

Tags: typescript

I don't know how to define a type alias for an object containing two functions that can be composed:
I have tried this

```
type FunctionComposition<IntermediateType> = {
   f: (a: any) => IntermediateType;
   g: (b: IntermediateType) => any;
}
```

But when I want to use it to type an object without specifying IntermediateType, I get an error. How can I make the IntermediateType optional without losing the type constraint imposed by the output type of f being the input type of g?

I would like to use this during the startup of a web server. On each process I execute several steps where each step builds upon the output of the previous step.

For example, first database initialization, then http server ititialization, then websocket initialization, and so on.

I define these steps as a type

```
type Step<Output> = {
  boot: (input: any) => Output
  terminate: (output: Output) => any
}
```

I would like to drop the Output generic and let it be inferred, so that later in my code when I do

```
const output = step.boot()
...
step.terminate(output)
```

any error in mismatching output type is caught.

Comment: You can't. It is only possible by using the inference of a generic function.

Comment: TS doesn't have *existentially quantified generics* so you can't simply express "`type FunctionComposition = <exists T>{f: (a: any) => T; g: (b: T) => any}`" which is what you're looking for.  There are various workarounds, but without a more detailed use case it's hard to tell which of these would be appropriate. Could you [edit] with examples of how you would intend to use `FunctionComposition`?

Comment: @jcalz, okay I have added more info

Comment: Could you provide *code examples* that show you using your desired `FunctionComposition` type?  Specifically a [mre]?  Right now I don't understand why all the initialization steps can't hold onto the generic type argument if it needs them, or if it doesn't, why you don't package the execution of the composed functions into a single thunk-like function.  If you provide code examples I can try to modify those examples to make them work.  But right now it's not concrete enough for me to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz, Actually, the simplest use case would be to simply call `step.terminate(step.boot())`. I was wondering whether it was possible to make this throw a typescript error if the intermediate type doesn't match without specifying it. You have talked about workarounds, which ones do you mean? If this simple case would work, I could also do it for more complicated types.

Comment: [These](https://tsplay.dev/wXz3Om) are the approaches I'd start to explore; either you want to carry the generic around with you, or you repackage the data in a nongeneric shell that hides the generic stuff inside, or you can go for the full existential type emulator.  I'd say the middle one is reasonable since the only plausible thing you probably want to do with `Step<T>` is call `boot()` once and then `terminate()` once with the result, so you don't need arbitrary access to the data.  Should I write this up as an answer?

Comment: @jcalz, wow thanks, that is a lot of code. It seems to work. So the key is the function `type SomeStep = <R, >(cb: <T, >(step: Step<T>) => R) => R;
const someStep = <T,>(step: Step<T>): SomeStep => cb => cb(step);` It doesn't require the type T. Inside the call back T is defined. Where did you learn these things? I could not find this stuff in the typescript documentation.

Comment: Would it be possible to replace the Step type in the SomeStep type by a generic?

Comment: It's a lot of code because it's three different approaches.  Which one do you want to see in the answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "replace the `Step` type in the `SomeStep` type by a generic"?  If you mean you want to inline the `Step` type definition, sure.  If you mean something else, could you explain?  (And... is this required for your question as asked or is it a followup question?)

Comment: @jcalz, I like the last approach most I think, since it is the shortest. I meant "could I turn Step into an arbitrary type and recycle this code for other similar types?".

Comment: What's an "arbitrary type"?  TS doesn't have direct support for *higher kinded types* as requested in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), so there's no way to abstract the whole universal-to-existential conversion as `type Existential<F> = <R>(cb: <T>(ft: F<T>)=>R) => R`.  You can't abstract apply type parameters to other type parameters (`F<T>` is invalid).  Can you confirm that this is just followup and not needed to answer the question?  I like talking about this stuff but comments are not really a great place for it